# How to unit test a lambda function written in python which connects to AWS secrets manager and RDS (mySQL)

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services

I would describe myself as a novice developer and am have written a lambda function in python which queries an RDS mySQL database.I coded this program on aws and am now trying to test it locally don't know where to start. I have tried using moto but my limited knowledge is making things very difficult. Any tips or pointers?

```
import json
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from rds_config import get_secret

resp_dict = json.loads(get_secret())
rds_client = boto3.client('rds-data')

# Connection Configuration Values
endpoint = resp_dict.get('host')
username = resp_dict.get('username')
password = resp_dict.get('password')
database_name = resp_dict.get('dbname')
port = resp_dict.get('port')

# Group Configuration Values
Group2 = "@email"

connection = pymysql.connect(host=endpoint, user=username, passwd=password, db=database_name, port=port)
cursor = connection.cursor()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Dump and load event data
    data = json.dumps(event)
    y = json.loads(data)

    # Get the email and username
    email = y['request']['userAttributes']['email']
    cognitoUsername = y['userName']

    # verify email and username are the same
    if email != cognitoUsername:
        raise Exception("Username and Email address must be the same")
    try:
        if checkGroup2(email):
            if searchGroup2TableAccountID(email):
                return event
            else:
                raise Exception("Group 2 user is not present in group 2 table")
        else:
            accountID = searchGroup1TableAccountID(email)
            if accountID is not None:
                status = searchOnboardingStatusTableOnboardingOutcome(accountID)
                if (status is not None) and (status == 'accepted'):
                    return event
                else:
                    raise Exception("User is not present in onboarding table")
            else:
                raise Exception("User is not present in Group1 table ")
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e.response['Error']['Message'])

def checkGroup2User(email):
    if "@email" in email:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def searchGroup1TableAccountID(email):
    sqlCheckEmail = "SELECT account_ID from group1 where email_address = %s"
    cursor.execute(sqlCheckEmail, (email,))
    accountID = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    return accountID

def searchOnboardingStatusTableOnboardingOutcome(accountID):
    sqlCheckStatus = "SELECT onboarding_outcome from onboarding_status where account_ID = %s"
    cursor.execute(sqlCheckStatus, accountID)
    status = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    return status

def searchGroup2TableAccountID(email):
    sqlCheckGroup2AccountID = "SELECT account_id from group2_account where user_email_address = %s"
    cursor.execute(sqlCheckGroup2AccountID, (email,))
    accountID = cursor.fetchone()
    return accountID
```

Comment: You can use boto3 from your laptop (as an example) and the lambda should run. The only important point is that the local credentials will have the same permissions as the lambda function.

Comment: @balderman thank you. I have got it up and running but cannot get mock/patching the rds database to work. Am I going about this in an unconventional way?

Comment: You can connect to a local MySQL - isn't it?